# Hover over alink and animate a div

Tags: jquery

Hi I have come to a halt in trying to get what I need to work.

Based on:

```
$(".test a").hover(function(){
        $(this).toggle({ height: "200px" });
    }, function() {
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({ height: "100px" });
    });
});

<div class="test">
  <a href="#one">1</a>
  <a href="#two">2</a>
  <a href="#three">3</a>
</div>
```

I need it to animate a `div` not the self one, I came up with the below, which animates it down, but not back up, etc:

```
$(".test a").hover(function(){
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); 

        $(activeTab).toggle({ height: "200px" });   }, function() {
        $(activeTab).stop(true, false).animate({ height: "100px" });    }); });

<div class="test">
<a href="#one">1</a>
<a href="#two">2</a>
<a href="#three">3</a>

<div id="one" class="tab one">1</div>
<div id="two" class="tab two">2</div>
<div id="three" class="tab three">3</div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redeclare the variable activeTab because it only exist in the scope of the mouseenter, not mouseout

```
$(".test a").hover(function(){      
          var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); 
          $(activeTab).toggle({ height: "200px" });   
     }, 
     function() {
          var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); 
          $(activeTab).stop(true, false).animate({ height: "100px" });   
     }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".test a").hover(function(){      var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); 

        $(activeTab).toggle({ height: "200px" });   }, function() {
        $(activeTab).stop(true, false).animate({ height: "100px" });    }); });
```

There are a few errors here... one is, count your brackets....

```
$(".test a").hover(function(){
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); 
    $(activeTab).toggle({ height: "200px" });
},
function() {
    $(activeTab).stop(true, false).animate({ height: "100px" });
});
}); // too many closing brackets
```

The second is that `var activeTab` is out of scope in the second function. So you need to redefine `var activeTab` in the second function:

This should work:

```
$(".test a").hover(function(){
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); 
    $(activeTab).toggle({ height: "200px" });
},
function() {
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); 
    $(activeTab).stop(true, false).animate({ height: "100px" });
});
```